# ¿Cómo alternar la visualización de un LinkButton dentro de un GridView según la selección de un CheckBox?

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Requerimiento**

Generar un control `GridView` que posea un `CheckBox` el cual, al ser seleccionado "Checked", muestre un `LinkButton` que permita a su vez, la descarga de un documento.

**Problema**

No encuentro la manera de detectar la activación el evento CheckedChanged del `CheckBox` para así mismo, cambiar el valor de visibilidad del `LinkButton`.

Ya que estos controles `CheckBox` y `LinkButton` se encuentran dentro de un `GridView`, una alternativa es recorrer cada fila del `GridView` para detectar los `CheckBoxes` seleccionados, pero, esta alternativa no es válida para este caso, ya que es necesario que *una vez seleccionado el CheckBox* **inmediatamente se muestre el LinkButton asociado en la fila del GridView.**

Éste es el código que tengo hasta el momento.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvEjemplo" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chk_allowDownloadDocument" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Cedula_Usuario" HeaderText="Elemento" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Descargar">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnDescargarDocumento" Text="Descargar" runat="server" CommandName="descDoc" />
            </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

¿Hay alguna manera de lograr este comportamiento?

---

1. He [intentado](https://stackoverflow.com/a/540834) [replicar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12692554) estos ejemplos, pero no encuentro otros ejemplos que tengan un enfoque similar.
2. En este [ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19628554), se usa el evento Command, pero el `CheckBox` no posee este atributo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para lograr el comportamiento que deseas, debes agregar el evento `OnCheckedChanged` al `CheckBox` del `GridView` y además de la propiedad que ya tienes que es `AutoPostback`. Te dejo un ejemplo que cree y está funcionando.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridview" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Nombre">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Nombre") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chk" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chk_CheckedChanged"/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="link" Text="Descargar" Visible="false" CommandName="descDoc"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

La columna Nombre la agregué solo para probar. Como puedes ver inicialicé el `LinkButton` en false.

Este es el CodeBehind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Nombre");

            dt.Rows.Add("Marco");
            dt.Rows.Add("Felipe");
            dt.Rows.Add("Eduardo");
            dt.Rows.Add("Mario");

            gridview.DataSource = dt;
            gridview.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Para obtener la fila lo obtengo del padre del padre del control `CheckBox`, ya que el padre es el `DataControlFieldCell` y el padre de este el el `GridViewRow`

```
    protected void chk_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow) chk.Parent.Parent;
        LinkButton link = (LinkButton)row.FindControl("link");
        link.Visible = chk.Checked ? true : false; 

    }
```

Comment: Con los ejemplos aportados en las respuestas de @@Leandro y de @@MBahamondes pude completar el requerimiento. Muchas gracias y +1 para ambas respuestas.

Answer (score 2):

Para acceder a la row del grid que lanza el evento desde el evento del checkbox debes usar el `NamingContainer`

[How to: Access Members of a Control's Naming Container](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/858twd77.aspx)

Podrias intentar algo como esto

```
piblic void chk_allowDownloadDocument(...)
{
   DataGridViewRow gridRow = sender.NamingContainer as DataGridViewRow;

  LinkButton link = gridRow.FindControl("lnkBtnDescargarDocumento") as LinkButton;
  link.Visible = false;

}
```