# ¿Cómo generar un control GridView dinámicamente que contenga controles internos?

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Requerimiento**

El sistema en el que estoy trabajando tiene una tabla llamada *área*, la cual contiene los nombres de las áreas que posee una empresa:

Ejemplo:

- Recursos Humanos
- Contabilidad
- Operaciones
- Gerencia
- *Entre otras...*

El control `GridView` *que inicialmente había generado para [mi pregunta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/4781)* muestra la información de una sola área, pero ahora, se debe generar **por cada área, un control `GridView`.**

Éste es el control `GridView` que debo generar por cada área.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvEjemplo" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
   <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="¿Área activa?">
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:CheckBox ID="chk_allowDownloadDocument" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
           </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Descripción">
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescr" runat="server" />
           </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Descargar">
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnDescargarDocumento" Text="Descargar" runat="server" CommandName="descDoc" />
           </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

He intentado adaptar el código fuente de esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20700407) para generar el `GridView`, así como también he intentado:

- Modificar la clase personalizada `ITemplate` para generar los controles en cada fila, pero no logro adaptar el código para que funcione con mas de un control __.
- Generar los controles en el evento `RowDataBound`
- *Intenté* [duplicar la estructura de un GridView a otro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12725541) *pero parece que esto no es posible.*

Pero las pruebas anteriores no me muestran los GridView generados.

**¿Hay alguna manera en la que pueda generar Controles GridView con una estructura similar a la indicada en esta pregunta?**

Answer (score 1):

Si la idea es generar `GridView` dinamicos podrias ubicar este dentro de un contorl `Repeater`

En el template del repeater defines el gridview para que se cree uno por cada dato que tengas. Por supuesto vas a tener que tener una jerarquiza de datos

[Adding Gridview nested in Repeater in ASP.NET 2.0](http://techbrij.com/adding-gridview-nested-in-repeater-in-asp-net-2-0)

Como veras defines algo como ser

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server"
        onitemdatabound="rpt_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="Grd" runat="server">            
        </asp:GridView>
    </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:Repeater>
```

el ejemplo es algo simple, el gridview dentro del temaplate puede ser el que has puesto en tu codigo definiendo las columnas.

Debes usar el evento `ItemDataBound` para asignar los datos del grid

```
protected void rpt_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        GridView gv = (GridView)e.Item.FindControl("grd");
        if (gv != null)
        {
            DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
            gv.DataSource = GetSubData(Convert.ToInt32(drv["ID"]));
            gv.DataBind();            
        }
    }
}
```

por eso veras que se usa el `e.Item.DataItem` para poder cargar los datos de cada area.

De esta forma tienes dos niveles, el primero seran las areas y el segundo los datos de cada una de estas.

Answer (score 0):

Hola hay diversas maneras de hacerlo, una manera sencilla seria creando los gridviews por codigo y para cada gridview le asignas su pertinente datasource(dataset o datatable...)

Paras crear 2 o mas gridviews por codigo se ha ce asi:
 Dim grid1, grid2 As New GridView

Para asignarles el datasource asi:

grid1.DataSource = DATASOURCE1
 grid2.DataSource = DATASOURCE2

y para que cargar y que puedas ver los datos  no olvides hacer:

```
    grid1.DataBind()
    grid2.DataBind()
```